# Uploading a bitmap to the server with http protocol

Tags: android

i have a camera Activity after which i take a picture  and saving it to gallery and uploading to the server My upload  code  is not working, i need  help on this?

// image capture

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

//image Saving

```
if(requestCode==0&&resultCode==RESULT_OK)

{

    Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
    Bitmap b = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");

    ImageView mImg;
    mImg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.head);
    mImg.setImageBitmap(b);

    // save image to gallery
    Shot = "HeadShot"; //Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis());
    MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), b, Shot, NAME);

}
```

//Upload to  the server

```
public void Upload(String url, HttpEntity imgdata) throws Exception, Exception {

    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
    post.setHeader("Content-Type", "bitmap; charset=utf-8");
    post.setURI(new URI(url));
    post.setEntity(imgdata);
    HttpUriRequest request = post;
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    return entity.getContent();
}
```