# Upload an image / bitmap through HTTP from Android

Tags: android, image, http, post, bitmap

I want to upload a bitmap to a php server through HTTP / POST. I saw some solutions, which used base64 encoding to POST the image, but in my eyes this approach seems a bit inconsistent. Are there better ways to upload the image?

Best regards,
Lukas

Comment: http://www.coderzheaven.com/2012/04/26/upload-image-android-device-server-method-4/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3202627/uploading-a-bitmap-to-the-server-with-http-protocol  .. lots of solutions for this scenario

Answer (score 0):

Use the [FileEntity](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/entity/FileEntity.html) in your post.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bitmap class, then change the value of 100

```
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
```

else place your code.

hope this work.